# Upper bound on least eigenvalue of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

I found this result in a [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379508X00072/1-s2.0-S0024379508001067/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIEJeuBOn9AOMepoJ%2FykxOQ5FUOh9K7p4gad%2FEq%2BTcbrQAiEAvAo0YRhlPv08xMwnGXaawrgr%2FnTRDhgf0r00NElC99QqugUIxv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDDOv3o8ttvO3GE68kCqOBZRqYFL0Qkfkk1sDfohpcNlS%2BHssOq3hOyXwXq9QejlUNFtSfTH6xPDNpjYMMCz2iB07vFWeW6o%2BVjYLeL5WVePpDnyxDSSNlOOa%2BeipehifoNhgpFjlqMDlE5cJVqVXVCO472IpXGctfJgLMyrevsd8O%2FDgfqxWwTnGEs%2B7u0V162Oc4kX0pp4eqKIlQ1ZzsEIKAIUcZ1Y7or60GOzEpvcvBQgOMa2queaJK7TDsnG1plYaVV8RqyfoEd%2Fd1veNPTufqPYyFeIut9I%2BRasK9alYl%2BgeFZMJCvqLN81qgeODymqzt8OnAIBSUXnUXer2oKAYGhZKFRiokzt675MSQFEW%2BH7U8J5X7eA2lAyfptuS4iBTxOISJA5OJQZmwRot4T4fC9kmEup8B3BZ99nmuyUuy8wK1m47IOgCGTCUwPUbfEmO%2FoNeSj%2FVLUnSpT00lLvcGQTVK54g49oZqD9fQMJTgleDzZpTa5i13d6UbH%2FTs5ZNJ5vTkt4WpbZrAOhYWG2vmoQGMsW2%2FjKqH%2FFxp4pqv5Rwp7wRe2wLwbwDnMW353o8%2BUF8lHnUSA1MYx17kO55Jhi5Al9cU7hjBwjxzUYxKn0fmlR7JgprHEdOYhMSru95d0X%2FlhBtYh1HyDpqf8eoef7QiJdbtS%2BQ9GdLGg4GVdLJvdDI7O90bPGt1%2FCUDQCn1fQH92sROHQ9glcv7nyz2sO%2FYU6WcCgPohuTQkieXKNYh61Grm%2BqEG61L%2FymOumdVnOOGodC73ZyIXPq3eLUsqce6NYVSrMPq90w4ElLYe%2FuDdY0KaIAy8py2vvA48vcVXkFCp4zuPrAFNngM8rAtb%2FkpmU%2FOdue7RRxRbEBKlh5mY49gDrhp72qSjCekZGiBjqxAZqSNowstDt2mAFeQltbRR%2Btv0CkpigC1An21qGDsBImwYekpAaIgykGWO0KsmMSh%2F0%2BUEuUJAx7z8kH8NlDJea%2FHLkufUdFF72n1O4tuJ6553Xwvcto3wOTxBpATItMtZ5f5vHjHp2KB%2FhI3qahSU5SOISDphA8bWmyooMyxsX2ts95Q0QljKy%2BfVqX6MC5%2B5sVMW%2FTs6vlaP0GXVdLghE7nWsz4nXXKyoVr1cmIlV5RA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230422T214925Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZRNNIZZE%2F20230422%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=014a1697a831981aa94dd15c089c24a03dae88b04c56774d4636669d660bd41b&hash=2f8d75412c57619f7700c3dd68f4af43af44d26ffcdf09e3423c6d5e007c75c3&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0024379508001067&tid=spdf-d268acae-a28c-4a70-9f71-732a0cbfcec7&sid=ff7558137f3d4743bb4b89d41c42bacfec32gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f15520c05535f56570e06&rr=7bc1139af84c1131&cc=us): "Much less is known about the least eigenvalue [in comparison to the spectral radius]. Recall first that the least eigenvalue of any graph is non-positive. It is equal to zero only for totally disconnected graphs. Otherwise, for graphs with at least one edge, it is less than or equal to $-1$ (by the Interlacing Theorem)."

I am curious how to prove the last statement through employing the interlacing theorem for real symmetric matrices. I just can't seem to crack it. Here's my attempt:

Let $G$ be a non-empty graph with adjacency matrix $A$, meaning it has at least one edge.
Since $G$ has at least one edge, there exists a vertex $v$ in the graph $G$ with a degree of at least $1$ (i.e., it has at least one neighboring vertex). Let $G'$ be the subgraph of $G$ obtained by removing vertex $v$ and all its incident edges. Let $B$ be the adjacency matrix of $G'$. $B$ is obtained by removing the $v$-th row and the $v$-th column of $A$.

Now we can apply the interlacing theorem:

Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, and $B$ is obtained by removing one row and one column from $A$, the eigenvalues of $B$ interlace the eigenvalues of $A$: if $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \ldots \leq \mu_{n-1}$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, then:

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 \leq \mu_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \mu_2 \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_{n-1} \leq \mu_{n-1} \leq \lambda_n
\end{equation}

$G'$ is obtained from $G$ by removing a vertex and its incident edges, which means $G'$ has fewer edges than $G$. Since $G$ is non-empty and $G'$ has fewer edges, $G'$ cannot be a complete graph. The smallest eigenvalue of a complete graph is $0$, so the smallest eigenvalue of $G'$, $\mu_1$, must be strictly less than $0$.

So by the interlacing property

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 \leq \mu_1
\end{equation}

But here's where the proof breaks down, because I'm not sure where $-1$ comes into play, and it's not like I can claim the eigenvalues must be integers. How can I prove the required statement?

Comment: Sketch: Argue that  the adjacency matrix can be diagonalized, And the trace is $0$ so the sum of the eigenvalues is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph $H$ with two vertices and a single edge between them has two eigenvalues: $\beta_1 = -1$ and $\beta_2 = 1$.

If a graph $G$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \dots \le \lambda_n$ and contains the induced subgraph $H$ (that is, contains an edge), then the interlacing theorem says that $\lambda_1 \le \beta_1 \le \lambda_{n-1}$ and $\lambda_2 \le \beta_2 \le \lambda_n$. In particular, $\lambda_1 \le -1$.